# Every function has dependency on $P,V,T$

Tags: thermodynamics, differentiation, degrees-of-freedom

Whenever equation like 
$$dF=\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\right)_ydx+\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\right)_x dy$$ comes $x,y$ are always any two of $\textbf{pressure,volume & temperature}$ only.
What's the cause?

Comment: -1 Not clear what you are asking. Are these 3 the only variables you use in your thermodynamics course? There is no reason why other state variables cannot be used.

Comment: Who says it cannot be U?

Comment: see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/468754/

Answer (score 0):

It's really just a coincident, the equation is general for any calculation of small change to a function F of two variables x and y.